# Google Analytics conversions for Travel Agency

Tags: google-analytics

what is  the best way to track orders for travel agency via Google Analytics?

There is major difference between typical e-shop and travel agency - in e-shop there is simple basket with products. In order systems of travel agency, in other hand, there are no "products" and passenger price depends on location.

Agency offers several destinations (hotels) which have different pricing for each age category etc..

I could use passenger as "transaction item", but I can not find any way to tell, which hotel/destination is bound to this order (which would be very useful for generating reports).

Is there any way to tell transaction which destination is client traveling to (and use passengers as transaction items)? Or other way to analyze client orders keeping both information about passengers and destination?

I am using "ecommerce" module of GA: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

Comment: Well, one way of approaching this issue is by taking advantage of Google Tag Manger and DataLayer array - So basically once a traveller checks out you pass the value of the transaction to DataLayer which is then triggered in Google Analytics ... I guess you now have a few questions - if yes, let me know and I draw up an example later and a few links that help you setting it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one way of approaching this issue is by taking advantage of [Google Tag Manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/) and DataLayer array - So basically once a traveller checks out you pass the value of the transaction to DataLayer which is then triggered in Google Analytics ... I guess you now have a few questions - if yes, let me know and I draw up an example later and a few links that help you set it up.